# Map result of json_agg() using JPA native query to nested projection

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I have to query a database to get information about user inquiries and files attached to them.
An inquiry can have many files attached to it.

For that I use a native JPA query. The most important excerpts from it are below:

```
@Query(value = """
    select
        i.id as "id",
        coalesce(
                json_agg(
                        json_build_object( 'fileName', if.file_path, 'fileSize', if.size)
                ) filter (where if.uuid is not null), '[]') as "files"
    from inquiry i
    left join inquiry_file if on if.inquiry_id = i.id
    ...
    group by 
    -- for json_agg() to work
    """, nativeQuery = true
)
List<InquiryProjection> getInquiries(...);
```

Below is the code for the corresponding projections:

```
public interface InquiryProjection {

  UUID getId();

  List<FileProjection> getFiles();

}

public interface FileProjection {

  String getFileName();

  Long getFileSize();

}
```

However when I execute the code on a DB containing 1 inqury with 2 files,
only the fields of InquiryProjection will be correctly initialized (`InquiryProjection.id` in the example).

To check contents of inquiry files I use the code below:

```
var files = inquiryProjection.getFiles();
var file1 = files.get(0);
```

I can see in debugger window:

```
file1 = {$Proxy304@29197} [{"fileName" : "file1.doc", "fileSize" : 300}, {"fileName" : "file2.pdf", "fileSize" : 500}]
```

which is strange because it contains JSON describing both files.

And then when I try to get the file name:

```
var file1Name = file1.getFileName();
```

The following error will occur:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'fileName' of bean class [java.lang.String]: Could not find field for property during fallback access
    at org.springframework.data.util.DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.getPropertyValue(DirectFieldAccessFallbackBeanWrapper.java:55)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.PropertyAccessingMethodInterceptor.invoke(PropertyAccessingMethodInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectingMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProjectingMethodInterceptor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.ProxyProjectionFactory$TargetAwareMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProxyProjectionFactory.java:243)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy304.getFileName(Unknown Source)
```

Is it possible to get it working?

I know that the problem in this simple example can be solved with other means - for example with non-native JPA-query and "left join fetch" or entity graphs, so that I have inquiry entities at the end and can access their files as collections via getters. But I want to understand whether the approach with native query and nested projections works.

If you know how to accomplish it with non-interface based projections, please suggest it as well.

I'm using:

```
Java 17
PostgreSQL 15.3
Hibernate 6.2.6
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:3.1.2
```